# cannot receive query parameter from link

Tags: php

admin.php

```
<?php

    require_once('database_connect.php');

    $category_no = empty($_POST['category_no']) ? Null : $_POST['category_no'];
    $_get_page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;
//    $_get_query = $_GET["q"];


    $csql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as 'cnt' FROM inquiries"; // 総件数カウント用SQL

    if(isset($category_no)) {
        $ssql ="SELECT name, email, contact, inquiry, CASE when category_id = '1' then '無料体験' when category_id = '2' then '料金について' when category_id = '3' then '入会つい' ELSE 'その他' END AS category_name FROM inquiries where category_id = ${category_no} limit 10 offset :start";

    }else {

        $ssql ="SELECT name, email, contact, inquiry, CASE when category_id = '1' then '無料体験' when category_id = '2' then '料金について' when category_id = '3' then '入会ついて' ELSE 'その他' END AS category_name FROM inquiries limit 2 offset :start";
    }
//

    // データ抽出用SQLを、プリペアドステートメントで実行
    $ssth = $pdo->prepare($ssql);
//    $ssth->bindValue(":q", $_get_query);
    $ssth->bindValue(":start", ((int)$_get_page-1) * 2, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $ssth->execute();
    $data = $ssth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // 総件数カウント用SQLを、プリペアドステートメントで実行
    $csth = $pdo->prepare($csql);
//    $csth->bindValue(":q", $_get_query);
    $csth->execute();
    $total = $csth->fetchColumn(0);

    $pages = ceil((int)$total / 2); // 総件数÷1ページに表示する件数 を切り上げたものが総ページ数
    echo $pages;



?>
   <html>
       <head>
           <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
           <title>花見川IT寺小(管理者画面)</title>
           <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
           <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/hannari.css" rel="stylesheet">
           <link rel='stylesheet' href='./css/style_admin.css' type='text/css'>
       </head>

           <body>

        <form method='post' action='admin.php'>
            <select name='category_no' onchange='submit(this.form)'>
                <option value='1'>無料体験</option>
                <option value='2'>料金について</option>
                <option value='3'>入会について</option>
                <option value=''>無し</option>
            </select>
        </form>
           <?php
           foreach($data as $row) {
               printf("<li>%s</li>\n", $row["name"]);
               printf("<li>%s</li>\n", $row["email"]);
               printf("<li>%s</li>\n", $row["contact"]);
               printf("<li>%s</li>\n",$row["category_name"]);
               printf("<li>%s</li>\n", $row["inquiry"]);
               echo '_______________________________________';
           }
           ?>
           </ul>

              <?php

                  function pagination($totalPage, $page) {

                      $page = (int)$page;
                      $prev = max($page-1, 1);
                      $next = min($page+1, $totalPage);

                      if($page!=1) {

                          printf("<a href='?page='%q'>&laquo 前へ</a>", $prev);
                      }

                      if($page < $totalPage) {

                          printf("<a href='?page='%q'>&raquo 次へ</a>", $next);

                      }

                  }

                  pagination($pages, $_get_page);


            ?>
       </body>
   </html>
```

When push below links, i was supposed to get some query parameter which is 'page'.

```
 <?php

                  function pagination($totalPage, $page) {

                      $page = (int)$page;
                      $prev = max($page-1, 1);
                      $next = min($page+1, $totalPage);

                      if($page!=1) {

                          printf("<a href='?page='%q'>&laquo 前へ</a>", $prev);
                      }

                      if($page < $totalPage) {

                          printf("<a href='?page='%q'>&raquo 次へ</a>", $next);

                      }

                  }
```

but even do that, cannot received it only see query variable without value in search window like below.

'http://localhost:8888/IT_Temple/admin.php?page='

How should i do to get the query with variable?

I would be very happy if someone have a solution of that problem.

Thank you.

Comment: You have `'?page='%q'`, so you need to sort out which quotes you want to use - probably `'?page=%q'` (although not sure why it's `%q`)

Answer (score 0):

there is an extra single quote `'?page='%q'` should be `'?page=%q'`

```
if($page!=1) {
    printf("<a href='?page=%q'>&laquo 前へ</a>", $prev);
}
if($page < $totalPage) {
    printf("<a href='?page=%q'>&raquo 次へ</a>", $next);
}
```